# wordpress calls templates in wrong order

Tags: wordpress

I put a taxonomy.php file, but when accessing the page, it will not access the taxonomies file unless I delete the arrchive.php file. This should conflict with the mechanism of wordpress, how should I correct this problem?

Comment: File name should be `taxonomy.php` (singular), not `taxonomies.php`. See [Template Hierarchy - Custom Taxonomies](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#custom-taxonomies) for more details.

Comment: Sorry, it is taxonomy.php,I made a typo when submitting my question.